# How to pass ifdef keyword by using makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I want to use "#ifdef MYFLAG" in my C code to exclude certain code parts when the keyword "MYFLAG" is passed to the compiler. So far so good. The project is compiled with a makefile.

Now, I can't figure out yet if it is correct to write

$ ./project/ make -MYFLAG

and then set the #ifdef as true. It compiles the files, but the size of the output remains unchanged. Do changes have to be made in the Makefile to accept the keyword or is it enough to have #ifdef in the c code and pass it as above?

Comment: `./project/ make` doesn't look legal in the first place. No, you can't pass defines to a makefile like this; you need cooperation from the makefile (it has to have variables that could be modified from Make flags to add compiler flags).

Comment: Assuming the `$ ./project/ ` is your command prompt, `make -MYFLAG` tells `make` to rebuild the target `-MYFLAG` -- which is probably not what you intended/wanted.  Please [edit] your question to show the `makefile` and relevant `C` code.  My guess is that you want to set or modify `CPPFLAGS`.

Comment: You would have to show your Makefile.  A well behaved makefile will always pass `CFLAGS` to the compiler and (slightly less standard but just barely so) `CPPFLAGS` to the preprocessor.   So if your Makefile follows conventions, you can probably just do `make CPPFLAGS=-DMYFLAG`.  If that doesn't work, then your Makefile is arguable broken and ought to be edited.

Comment: It's was when we were building the pyramids that I did this kinda stuff... Back then, one could set an environment variable and make would/could pass that to the compiler command. Sometimes "", sometimes "-DFOOBAR"... Document(!) what's expected lest it become a baffling mystery to others. Alternatively, a separate 'target' could be present in the makefile (eg: `make shortversion`).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do in your Makefile is check whether MYFLAG is set, then pass it to the compiler (typically with -D or /D). Example Makefile for this:

```
ifneq ("$(MYFLAG)", "")
        CFLAGS=-DMYFLAG=$(MYFLAG)
endif

.c.o:
        gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

The first three lines set CFLAGS depending on whether MYFLAG is set or not. Then in the rule how to compile .c files (last two lines), CFLAGS (which could be empty or contain -DMYFLAG is passed to the compile command (gcc -c).

Now just run make like

```
MYFLAG=1 make
```

and MYFLAG will be defined as 1.

Comment: Or you can set flags directly, something like `make FLAGS=-DMYFLAG`.

Comment: But don't do this!  The convention is to always pass `CFLAGS` to the compiler, and using a non-standard name like `FLAGS` just flaunts convention.

Comment: You are correct about using standard names where possible, the above was just some quickly put down example. I edited it to change it to CFLAGS.

Comment: Just a warning with using this -- If you run make once with MYFLAGS set, and then do another make with it unset, the second invocation of make will consider the .o file up to date, and not rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

@treus's answer is good, but it has a sharp stick -- if you do two subsequent makes, one with MYFLAG set, and one without, any artifacts created by the first will be considered up to date, and not be rebuilt, even though the CFLAGS has changed.   One solution to get around this:

Add a flag to the make line as so:

```
make MYFLAG=y
```

Then, in the makefile, process this *first*, as so:

```
ifdef MYFLAG
CFLAGS += -DMYFLAG=$(MYFLAG)
endif

OBJ_SUFFIX := $(shell echo $(CFLAGS) | md5sum | head -c 6)

# not allowed changing CFLAGS below this line...

OBJDIR = objs/$(OBJ_SUFFIX)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

...
```

This way, each time you change the CFLAGS, it will build to a different object directory, so artifacts will not be considered up to date incorrectly.